# Lodash & Bower: best way to specify underscore "drop in replacement" version

Tags: javascript, bower, lodash

I'm a bit of a bower newb.

When using bower to install lodash, the default version is **[dist/lodash.compat.js](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/bower.json)** but I'd like to instead use **dist/lodash.UNDERSCORE.js**

Is there a way to paramertise the `bower i lodash` to use the underscore version?
(I'd rather not edit the lodash package.json)

EDIT: Changed second lodash variation to lodash.underscore.js

Comment: You don't want to use `dist/lodash.compat.js`, but you do want to use `dist/lodash.compat.js`. What?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the question from the wording here, but are you saying you want to do `bower i lodash` and have it install underscore instead?

Comment: BaaahhhhH!!! I made a typo - the second version was supposed to be lodash.underscore.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently can't override the default "main" files in a bower package unfortunately, but there is an [open pull request for the bower.json spec that would let you do just that.](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec/pull/27)

If you want to use any files in a bower package not defined as main, you have to manually specify the paths to them in your scripts.

(There are some other solutions though if say you're doing this in the context of a task runner like Gulp or Grunt.)

Comment: Actually we are using gulp, what do you suggest?

Comment: I just realised you probably mean to include the file as per normal with gulp, that is what we currently have.